# Removing Polylines sequentially from a map

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, mapbox

My map app draws lines between a number of points. It is triggered by a play button, a pause button and a skip button to fast forward to the next location.

I create the route by working out lat longs that fall between the various points. This creates the microLineArray array. I also have a counter microIteration so I know where I am on the route.

I then draw the line between the 2 lat longs using the following in a loop

```
polyline.addLatLng(microLineArray[microIteration])
```

Everything works fine with the play, pause and fast forward. I now need to add reverse play and skip back function so I need to remove these lines.

First thinking was adding the above to an array using something like this.

```
added_lines.push(polyline.addLatLng(microLineArray[microIteration]));
```

this populates an array of all the plotted polylines, you can see a top level snapshot of this array value below.

[image: Example Array Value]

All of the other answers I have found on here tell me to remove the layer with the polylines but I want to keep that layer and step backwards. How do I go about removing the lines from the map now?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are tracking where you are on the route...why can't you splice off the index of the latLng that creates the line you don't want anymore with `spliceLatLngs`? The docs are at http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-splicelatlngs. You only need the first two parameters, index + amount to remove(which I think in the scenario you are describing would always be 1).

Comment: Don't suppose you have any example code for this. Can't seem to get it to work at the moment.